# What is the default file read/write location?

Tags: iphone

Whenever I write to a file (using methods such as `NSArray writeToFile:atomically:", I first use:

```
NSString* rootDir=[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* fileName=[rootDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"my_file_name"];
```

Where is the file written to if I just write to `@"my_file_name"` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be written into your application folder, but , in this case, `NSArray writeToFile:atomically:` will return `NO` as you won't have permission to write there

Answer (score 1):

It will write it to whatever the application has set as it's current directory. Paths are relative to `[NSFileManager currentDirectoryPath]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it and see. You might be surprised.

I would expect it to defer to the POSIX layer; i.e. it writes to the "current directory". Surprisingly, on iOS, the current directory is / and not /var/mobile/Applications/SOME-GUID-ABCDEF/MyApp.app (or wherever it's installed to these days) or its parent. In GDB, you can try something like `print (char*)getcwd((char*)0,(size_t)0)` (note that this leaks...).

You can also try `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"MyImage.png"]` or `var/mobile/Applications/.../MyApp.app/MyImage.png` (omitting the leading / to make it a relative path) to see if it looks in your app's bundle directory.

Either way, I'd avoid relying on it in case Apple decides to change behaviour in future OS versions.